# Do multi-parameter unitary subgroups exist?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, quantum-mechanics, unitary-matrices, quantum-groups

I'm working with an $N$-dimensional quantum system that is defined by the following Hamiltonian

$$
H = H_{\text{drift}} + \sum_{j=1}^n a^j H_{\text{drive}}^j 
$$

Where $n \ll N$ (in my case $n = 4$ and $N = 42$)

The unitary matrix in $SU(N)$ generated from $\text{span}\{H_{\text{drift}}, H^j_{\text{drive}}\}$ is presumably in an $(n + 1)$-parameter subgroup of $SU(N)$.  I know about one-parameter subgroups so I'm basically asking if *multi-parameter subgroups* are a thing? And also, if they are, if there are any known parameterizations of them?

Comment: You are asking about compact connected Lie groups of dimension $>1$. They definitely exist and a lot is known about them. Start by looking in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong but your Hamiltonian looks a lot like the basic formulation of quantum control theory: there one extends the usual time-dependent Schrödinger equation $\dot\psi(t)=-\frac{i}\hbar H_{\sf drift}\psi(t)$ by control terms to arrive at a bilinear control system:
$$
\dot\psi(t)=-\frac{i}\hbar\Big(H_{\sf drift}+\sum_ju_j(t)H^j_{\sf drive}\Big)\psi(t)
$$
Here the $u_j(t)$ are control functions, i.e. locally integrable functions which an experimenter can choose freely.
If one works with [general mixed states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_state#Mixed_states) (and not just pure states) one analogously turns the [Liouville-von Neumann equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix#The_Von_Neumann_equation_for_time_evolution) $\dot\rho(t)=-\frac{i}\hbar[H_{\sf drift},\rho(t)]$ into a controlled version:
$$
\dot\rho(t)=-\frac{i}\hbar\Big[H_{\sf drift}+\sum_ju_j(t)H^j_{\sf drive},\rho(t)\Big]
$$
The most basic question one asks in this setting is the question of **"reachability"**: given some initial state $\psi_0$ ($\rho_0$), which states $\psi_F$ ($\rho_F$) can one generate using the control Hamiltonians at hand? Shifting perspective one can also ask about gate reachability: the set of all solutions to
$$
\dot U(t)=-\frac{i}\hbar\Big(H_{\sf drift}+\sum_ju_j(t)H^j_{\sf drive}\Big)\quad \text{ with }\quad U(0)={\bf 1}\tag{1}
$$
is the set of all quantum gates (unitary operations) one can implement via the drift & controls at hand. While there are most relevant follow up questions like generating a reachable state or gate using controls which are optimal in some sense -- a central tool for which [Pontryagin's maximum principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin%27s_maximum_principle) -- let us focus on reachability.
The reason for this is that Lie theory turns out to be of immense use here:

As long as one has access to at least all control functions $u_j(t)$ which are piecewise constant (NB: which is quite reasonable with modern digital equipment) then solutions to the above equation are products of operators of the simple form $e^{-\frac{i}\hbar t(H_{\sf drift}+\sum_ju_jH^j_{\sf drive})}$, that is, time-independent operators which are also featured in your question. In this case an essential tool for analyzing reachability is the **system Lie algebra** $\mathcal A:=\langle H_{\sf drift},H^j_{\sf drive}:j\rangle_{\sf Lie}$, i.e. $\mathcal A$ is the smallest Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak u(n)$ [(=the Lie algebra of the unitary group ${\bf U}(n)$)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_group) which contains $H_{\sf drift}$ as well as all $H^j_{\sf drive}$. Side note: this may sound a bit abstract at first but this object is quite simple to handle on a computer. Either way one has the following fundamental result:

> **Theorem.** Let $G := \langle \exp(\mathcal A)\rangle$ denote the system group of control system (1), that is, $G$ is the smallest subgroup of ${\bf U}(n)$ that contains $\exp(\mathcal A)$). If $G$ is a closed subgroup of ${\bf U}(n)$, then then the set of all unitary matrices that can be generated via (1) (called "reachable set") coincides with the system group $G$.

A direct consequence of this is a very simple criterion for "controllability" (="one can generate all unitaries") via dimension counting:

> **Corollary.** If all Hamiltonians are chosen traceless, then system (1) is controllable if and only if $\operatorname{dim}(\mathcal A)=\operatorname{dim}(\mathfrak{su}(n))=n^2-1$. Otherwise (1) is controllable iff $\operatorname{dim}(\mathcal A)=\operatorname{dim}(\mathfrak u(n))=n^2$.

I'll keep it at that for now, but I'll gladly add some more detail if this is what your question aimed at.
As for further literature:

- [G. Dirr and U. Helmke, "Lie Theory for Quantum Control", *GAMM-Mitteilungen* 31 (2008), pp. 59–93](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/gamm.200890003); the above theorem is Theorem 3.3 in said paper
- D. D’Alessandro. *Introduction to Quantum Control and Dynamics*. Chapman & Hall/CRC, Boca Raton, 2008
- or Chapter 3.3 in my PhD thesis ["Reachability in Controlled Markovian Quantum Systems"](https://doi.org/10.14459/2020md1559809)

Comment: Frederik, thanks so much for the insight here, I ran a calculation on my hamiltonians and my system is indeed controllable -- interestingly certain subsets of the system hamiltonians do lead to a controllable system -- but the combination of the drive term with any of the other 4 is